# Is it possible to downgrade my apps required API level after publishing?

Tags: android

I have an app that requires API 14. I want to work on it so that it works on api 11. is it possible to downgradethe api level after publishing or would google not allow it?

Comment: Do you mean it should work on 11 and 14 as well? or Just 11?

Answer (score 1):

## Its possible.

You need to increase your `versionCode` in `AndroidManifest` and release this as an update.

Note: Any changes you make affects only future users. For example, if you increase your min API level, existing users are not kicked off (uninstalled). They will just not receive an update.

Similarly, this change you are making will show your app, in the play store, to people running lesser android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Google allows your changes in MINIMUM SDK Version i did it practically with my application